# Postfix. Always send email to outside

Tags: email, postfix

The problem:
I have 2 emails:

info@myhost.com

clientmail@anotherhost.com

When email is sent with help of PHP the email to clientmail@anotherhost.com is delivered, but email to info is not - user info doesn't exists.

I have postfix installed on myhost.com server, and no email server.

How to make postfix send mails to outside world to address info@myhost.com?

Comment: "no email server" -> postfix is not listening on port 25.

Comment: If you have Postfix, then you _do_ have a mail server.  Your question needs to explain where you want the mail to go, given that your mail system appears, without such an explanation, to be doing the right thing.  (Mail sent to a mailbox that is on the local system is delivered locally, failing if there's not in fact a mailbox by that name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have postfix installed ... and no email server.

Postfix *is* your mail server, and it uses local delivery if it discovers that your recipient's domain is the same as its own.

Edit `main.cf` and remove `myhost.com`, `$mydomain`, and similar entries from the `mydestinations` setting. This should make Postfix deliver messages to `myhost.com` over the network. (`$myhostname` and `localhost` can and perhaps even should remain.)